# Meaning of `A >: Null`?

Tags: scala

I attempted to write a function that won't compile if `null` is passed:

```
$scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_101).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :t null
Null

scala> def f[A >: Null](x: A):A = x
f: [A >: Null](x: A)A
```

However, it did not work as I expected:

```
scala> f( null )
res1: Null = null
```

Comment: `Null` is the lower bound, so it is allowed but no subtypes of null are allowed.

Comment: [Programming in Scala, 3rd edition](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_3ed), notes: `"Supertype
and subtype relationships are reflexive, which means a type is both a super-
type and a subtype of itself."`

Comment: That means that `A` can be both null or anything larger than null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has been pointed out, `A >: Null` allows for `A` to be `Null` itself, but that doesn't even matter here. Even if `A` were required to be a strict supertype of `Null`, it would still be possible to pass `null` to `f` as `null` is a valid value of those types (which follows directly from the fact that `Null` is a subtype of them).

If you don't want to accept nullable types, `A` needs to be a subtype of `AnyVal`. Note that this will prevent any values of reference types to be passed - not just `null` itself.

There is no way to accept reference types without also accepting null.

Answer (score 1):

[Scala specification section 3.5.2 (conformance)](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#conformance) states (emphasis mine):

> The `<:` relation forms *pre-order* between types, i.e. it is
>   **transitive and reflexive**. least upper bounds and greatest lower bounds
>   of a set of types are understood to be *relative to that order*.

So if we look at the type constructor declaration from a mathematical point of view, we see the `:<` relation as:

```
Null <: T <: Any
```

Since by definition the relation is reflexive, `Null <: Null` is in the relation, which makes null a valid value to be passed into the method.

As @sepp2k rightly said in the comments and in his answer, the fact that `A` isn't constrained by an upper bound means that `Any` is a valid candidate, which means a null value could be passed anyway.

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually matter. If `<:` weren't reflexive and thus `A` could only be a supertype such as `Any`, `null` would still be a valid argument as any function that accepts `Any` (or anything else that isn't `AnyVal`) accepts `null` as its argument.

Comment: @sepp2k I agree, but I wanted to emphasis the fact because of the way Kevin declared `Null` as a lower bound. Added a comment to emphasize.

Answer (score -1):

`A :> B` means that `A` is a super-type of `B`.
`A >: Null` this bound means that `A` is a super-type of `Null`.
`Null` [has](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Null.html) two super-types `Any` and `AnyRef`.

In Scala you can use `Option` as a good mechanism to avoid `null` usage.

What do you think about this?